# Get an extra row with a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume I have the following tables

```
CHAPTERS
| ID | Title        |
---------------------
|  1 | Introduction |

LINES
| ID | Chapter | Line                |
--------------------------------------
|  2 |       1 | Fourscore and ...   |
|  5 |       1 | In the beginning... |
```

What I'm looking for in my SQL result is the following

```
| Title        | Line       |
-----------------------------
| Introduction | null       |
| Introduction | Fourscore  |
| Introduction | In the beg |
```

So basically I want an extra row with just the Title and other rows with te matching lines.
All I've got now is just the 2 rows with the lines without the missing null-line with just the title.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select title,null as Line from chapters
union
select title,line from chapters a join lines b on a.id=b.chapter
```